Convert trace data into a graph of branches in IDA
I would like to record what branches my program took and then with the saved trace data convert it into a more readable form like a graph or map.
I want this to compare two scenarios and than see where another instanced branched of from the previous to figure out what part of the program checks a condition that determines which path the program takes.
Is that possible?
